# custom uitableviewcell highlight color

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm setting a custom uitableviewcell selection color as follows:

```
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc]initWithRed:250.0/255.0 green:250.0/255.0 blue:250.0/255.0 alpha:1];

    UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    bgColorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(240.0/255.0) green:(240.0/255.0) blue:(240.0/255.0) alpha:1.0];
    bgColorView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = bgColorView;
```

This works perfectly, except that because my UITableViewCell's regular background color is not white, when the fade out after the highlight occurs goes to white and then my background color instead of fading to my background color. Does anybody know how to get around this?

Comment: show us the whole cellForRowAtIndexPath method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting the background color of the `contentView`, set the `backgroundView` instead.

```
UIView *bgView = [[UIView alloc] init];
bgView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc]initWithRed:250.0/255.0 green:250.0/255.0 blue:250.0/255.0 alpha:1];
cell.backgroundView = bgView;

UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
bgColorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(240.0/255.0) green:(240.0/255.0) blue:(240.0/255.0) alpha:1.0];
bgColorView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
cell.selectedBackgroundView = bgColorView;
```

Answer (score 0):

The background is set up by the tableview after you return it from `tableview:cellFor...`. For that reason, cell background customization should be handled in [`tableView:willDisplayCell:...`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3awillDisplayCell%3aforRowAtIndexPath%3a)